# finding value gained where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript, function, math, percentage

I am trying to write a simple piece of script that will tell me the amount gained from the percentage difference between two values. This is what I have but it doesnt return the correct amounts.

```
function percentUP (money,newNum,Orignal){
    var increase = newNum - Orignal;
    var percent = Math.floor(Math.round(increase/Orignal*100));
    var gains = Math.round((money/percent)*100);
    
    return "you would make £" + gains + " from your " + "£" + money + " investment"
};
```

I have been testing it with a simple function of (10,30,10) a 200% increase, which should give me a result that reads:

**"you would make £30 from your £10 investment"**

but instead I get:
**"you would make £5 from your £10 investment"**

sorry if this is really obvious, I am just learning right now.

Comment: Isn't 10 to 30 a 200% increase?

Comment: sorry I put the wrong calculation that I made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake in `gains` calculation. Your `percent` is in your example equal 200. You want to multiply money by it and divide by 100.

Your calculation: `money / 200 * 100 = money / 2`
Expected calcualtion: `money * 200 / 100 = money * 2`

Corrected code:

```
function percentUP(money, newNum, orignal) {
  var increase = newNum - orignal;
  var percent = Math.round(increase / orignal);
  var gains = Math.round(money * percent);

  return `you would make £${gains} from your £${money} investment`
};
```

PS You could also remove `Math.round` call from `percent` calculation. It just messes accuracy.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I was not getting the mistake I had made at all, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Gains calculation seems wrong. It should be Original + (Original * Percent / 100). That should be 10 + (10 * 200/100). You could also use your money variable in the above example instead of Original. I wasn't sure of the difference based on what you are calculating.

Also, not sure what's the purpose of having a percentage in % form, it's simpler to just use the decimal form, ie, 2 instead of 200%. That way you avoid the conversion twice.

Comment: Damn you are right thank you for pointing that out, sorry for the way I have written it I am not used to JS yet, still learning slowly.